# Spring batch StoredProcedureItemReader

Tags: spring-batch

I get the following error when I run a stored procedure using Spring Batch:

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: L'index 0 du paramètre de sortie n'est pas valide.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:190)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerCallableStatement.getterGetParam(SQLServerCallableStatement.java:354)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerCallableStatement.getObject(SQLServerCallableStatement.java:659)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.StoredProcedureItemReader.openCursor(StoredProcedureItemReader.java:214)
    ... 18 more
```

The stored procedure contains a create table command which is responsible for the error.

The stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TEST]
    @orgKeyParam bigint
AS
BEGIN

CREATE TABLE #tmpPatients (
    programID bigint NOT NULL)

drop table #tmpPatients;

SELECT last_name from patient;
END
```

The StoredProcedureItemReader configuration:

```
<bean id="DBReader"
        class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.StoredProcedureItemReader">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource2" />
        <property name="procedureName" value="[${sql.RPMDBName}].dbo.Test" />
        <property name="fetchSize" value="50" />
                <property name="parameters">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlParameter">
                    <constructor-arg index="0" value="orgKeyParam" />
                    <constructor-arg index="1">
                        <util:constant static-field="java.sql.Types.INTEGER" />
                    </constructor-arg>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="rowMapper" ref="dataRowMapper" />
        <property name="preparedStatementSetter" ref="preparedStatementSetter" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="preparedStatementSetter"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.resource.ListPreparedStatementSetter" scope="step">
        <property name="parameters">
            <list>
                <value>1</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use nocount on in sql server stored proc.
Shoul b used before begin statement

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your stored procedure or the way you've configured your `StoredProcedureItemReader`, I can't give you an exact fix.  However, the error is that your parameter at index 0 is invalid.  By default, the `StoredProcedureItemReader` looks for the cursor that is returned to be the first out parameter.  I'm going to assume that either you've configured your reader to look elsewhere or your stored procedure isn't returning a cursor for it's first out parameter.

Comment: Hi, I have added the stored procedure and the batch configuration. Any idea what is wrong with it?

Comment: I'm not a SQL Server (or stored procedure) expert, but from the looks of things, you aren't returning a cursor from your stored procedure: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188655.aspx